# Can't install dependencies via npm in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, npm

I have downloaded Angular 2 from main site (quickproject) but I have a lot of problems with install additional libraries. When, for example I try to install angular2-modal module I get:

```
 npm install angular2-modal --save
angular-quickstart@1.0.0 C:\WebServ\httpd\quickstart
`-- angular2-modal@2.0.2

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.2.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.2.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.2.4 but none was installed.
```

I cannot install anything because of this fsevents I think. When I tried to do

```
npm update
```

I received

```
npm update --save
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WebServ\httpd\quickstart\npm-debug.log
```

How to repair it?

```
{


"name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^2.2.4",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.60",
    "angular-datatables": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.2",
    "fsevents": "^1.0.0",
    "angular2-modal": "^2.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^2.1.1",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^2.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "karma": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[fsevents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) is an OS X specific API that handles file notification events better on that operating system. Since you are on Windows, you can't run fsevents. It's OS X only.

The `npm WARN` messages you get are just warnings. It's skipping the optional fsevents dependency that you can't install on your OS. Some of the other warnings you get are a version mismatch between the Angular2 you want to install (2.4.3) and the one that angular2-modal wants as a peer (2.2.4), but this should *probably* work okay.

Remove `fsevents` from `package.json`. Some other dependencies may try to install it on OS X, but you don't need to include it as a core dependency of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything from node_modules. run "npm install" from terminal. then try to run "npm start". Make sure you have installed latest version of node & npm

Answer (score 0):

### Simple steps for downloading working Angular2 via NPM

1. Install NPM into your system
2. Install node.js into your system
3. Now follow follwing steps :-

Note :- For install Angular2 CLI globally 
Command : `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Step.1  `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` ( install angular dependencies )

Step.2  `ng new my-app` ( Creating New Angular2 Project )

Step.3  `cd my-app`  ( Comes to your project path )

Step.4  `ng serve --open` ( This command is for launching the server )

Open Your Angular2 project :- http://localhost:4200/